# Understand python image arrays

Tags: python, arrays, image

I can declare a 3D array like this:

## a 3D array, shape-(2, 2, 2)

```
3D_array = np.array([[[0, 1],[2, 3]], [[4, 5],[6, 7]]])
```

So if I have an image `10*10(pixels) 3 rgb` channels,  image.shape would be `(3x10x10)`.
But i see all the time image.shape equal to `(10x10x3)`, i don't understand why?

Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in numpy and matplotlib the rgb channels are in the last axis. This is just a convention, so you can do little about this. If you use a program that uses the other convention (channels first), you can transform the image with:

```py
channels_first_im = np.moveaxis(channels_last_im, 0, 1)
```

and the other way:

```py
channels_last_im = np.moveaxis(channels_first_im, 0, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're confused about why the convention image arrays would be of shape `(N, M, 3)` instead of `(3, N, M)`, let's look at how indexing would work in both of those scenarios.

Let's assume we have an image called `image_array`, that represents a random colored with a width and height of 100 pixels, and let's try to index it to access the value of the pixel at index `(50, 50)`.

#### Channels First

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.random((3, 100, 100)) #image.shape == (3, 100, 100)
pixel = image[:, 50, 50] #pixel.shape == (3,)
```

#### Channels Last

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.random((100, 100, 3)) #image.shape == (100, 100, 3)
pixel = image[50, 50] #pixel.shape == (3,)
```

Having the channels as the last dimension of the array, means that the individual pixel information is easier to index to find. Where as in the first case, we need to specify that we want the entire first dimension every time. These are inherently the same thing, but leaving the channels last allows us to be less verbose as to how we index the array.

Comment: Thanks four your clarification